How to extract surrounding html with bash?
I would like to read the href url that is stored next to the <td>blue</td> element:
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url1">url1</a>
        </td>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url2">url2</a>
        </td>
        <td>green</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

I first tried to capture the surrounding <tr> tag, but even this does not work:
#!/bin/bash
HTML_FILE="html_content.html"
tr_tag=$(grep -o '<tr>.*blue.*</tr>' "$HTML_FILE")
echo $tr_tag

My output is always blank. Why?

Keep in mind that using a regex to parse HTML is probably a bad idea. There are some really good bash tools that can do that.

@0stone0 oh okay, but I'd still prefer tools that are natively available eg in a ubuntu without extra installations.

If you really don't want to install something, you might just want to call python/purl from the CLI and create a script to parse it.

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and only reading 1 line at a time into memory, assuming your input is always formatted exactly as shown in your question:
$ awk -F'"' '/<a href="/{url=$2} /<td>blue<\/td>/{print url}' file
localhost/url1


If you are using GNU grep which supports PCRE, try this:
grep -z -Po '(?s)<tr>.*?blue.*?</tr>' "$HTML_FILE"


Your file has this line:
        <td>blue</td>

Your code:
grep -o '<tr>.*blue.*</tr>' 

So they don't match.
$: grep -o '<tr>.*blue.*</tr>' tst

$: grep -o '<td>.*blue.*</td>' tst
<td>blue</td>

If you are trying to grab the entire table row (<tr>) in which the table data (<td>) element with "blue" resides, grep doesn't generally do that sort of multiline matching by default (see below).
You could use sed or awk or perl, or even bash, but as mentioned elsewhere, remember that regexes tend to be greedy.
$: [[ "$f" =~ ( *<tr>.*blue.*</tr>) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url1">url1</a>
        </td>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url2">url2</a>
        </td>
        <td>green</td>
    </tr>

You need PCRE, or logic, and bash doesn't internally support PCRE in to my knowledge.
To get only the whole row of cells that match -
mapfile f < tst
for l in "${f[@]}"; do
  case $l in
  *"<tr>"*)  tr="$l";;
  *"</tr>"*) case $tr in *blue*) echo "$tr$l"; break;; esac;;
  *)         tr+="$l";;
  esac
done

Which gives
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url1">url1</a>
        </td>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>

In GNU sed, in case your grep dosn't know -P:
$: sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/{ H; /<\/tr>/{ x; /blue/{s/^\n//;p;Q} } }' tst
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url1">url1</a>
        </td>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>

A more portable version:
sed -n '
  /<tr>/,/<\/tr>/{ H 
                   /<\/tr>/{ x
                             /blue/{ s/^\n//
                                     p
                                     q
                                   }
                           }
                 }
 ' tst


The lovely grep provided by Philippe,
$: grep -z -Po '(?s) *<tr>.*?blue.*?</tr> *\n' tst
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="localhost/url1">url1</a>
        </td>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>

...explained a bit.
-o outputs only the match, as you already knew.
-P uses Perl-style PCRE matching.
-z tells grep the line-ending character is a null byte.
(?s) in the pattern says to treat the buffer as a single line, allowing . and such to match newlines (needed even with -z).
.* is greedy, so .*? says not to be, to instead match on minimal possibilities, so that no </tr> strings can be embedded in the middle as it searches for more.

In TXR:
$ txr bluehref.txr data.html
localhost/url1

Code in bluehref.txr:
@(skip)
        <td>
            <a href="@href">url1</a>
        </td>
        <td>blue</td>
@(output)
@href
@(end)

In color:

